# Como pegar valores CSS de um elemento e aplicar em outros elementos. Stick Footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Eu estou usando a solução [Stick Footer do Ryan Fait](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/), mas queria deixá-lo mais dinâmico usando JavaScript, permitindo que a altura do footer faça o cálculo automático dos outros valores das propriedades CSS dos outros elementos. Pode ser incluido inline mesmo.

Até agora eu consegui algo parecido com o que quero nessa função em jQuery. Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

Detalhe, eu substitui o `.wrapper` da solução do Ryan pelo `#content` no meu código.

```
$(function(){
    var footerHeight = $(".footer").height();
    $("#content").css("margin-bottom", -footerHeight);
    $(".push").css("height", footerHeight);
});
```

Comment: Você quer obter valores de cores e backgrounds ou apenas de altura/largura?

Answer (score 1):

a solução do Ryan não fala nada sobre cores seja da fonte ou background

mas se quer pegar css de um elemento faz a requisição assim

```
<script>
    var cor_texto = $('#Id_da_tag').css('color');
    var cor_background = $('#Id_da_tag').css('background');
    $('#id_destinno').css('color',cor_texto);
    $('#id_destinno').css('background',cor_background );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode atribuir o estilo de um elemento em outro da seguinte maneira:

```
$("#destino").attr("style", $("#origem").attr("style")).addClass($("#origem").attr("class"));
```